# getting segementaion fault when I declare Pointer to the string(Didn't try to modify it)

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am getting segmentaion fault when I Try to declare Pointer to the string like this `char *b = "This is String";` to check why sizeof() is always returning 8 but when I remove this line everything works great!!

here is My main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char *s;
    char *b = "how are you";
    printf("Enter the string:- ");
    for(int i =0;1;i++)
    {
        s = (char*)realloc(s,i+1);
        s[i]=getchar();
        if(s[i] == '\n')
        {
            s[i]= '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Your String:- %s \nAnd It's length:- %lu\nAnd the Size:- %lu",s,(strlen(s)),sizeof(s));
    printf(" \nThe size of b is %lu",(sizeof(b)));
}
```

If I remove the line `char *b = "how are you";` and `printf(" \nThe size of b is %lu",(sizeof(b)));` the program runs fine like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char *s;
    //char *b = "how are you";
    printf("Enter the string:- ");
    for(int i =0;1;i++)
    {
        s = (char*)realloc(s,i+1);
        s[i]=getchar();
        if(s[i] == '\n')
        {
            s[i]= '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Your String:- %s \nAnd It's length:- %lu\nAnd the Size:- %lu",s,(strlen(s)),sizeof(s));
    //printf(" \nThe size of b is %lu",(sizeof(b)));
}
```

OutPut

```
Enter the string:- I am Using Eclipse in Linux mint
Your String:- I am Using Eclipse in Linux mint 
And It's length:- 32
And the Size:- 8
```

**Why I can't Declare the string `char *b = "how are you";`**

Comment: The problem is that `s` is uninitialised before the first call of `realloc()`.    That causes `realloc()` to exhibit undefined behaviour.   Initialise `s` to `NULL` or to the result of a `malloc()` or `calloc()`.    The effect of adding or removing `b` or the `printf()` call is coincidental - they simply cause the program to have a different layout in memory, which causes `realloc()`s undefined behaviour to have different symptoms (e.g. due to changing WHAT is actually affected by the undefined behaviour).  PS:  don't cast the result of `realloc()`, and CHECK if it succeeds.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  3) When calling `realloc()`, always assign to the temporary variable, then check (!=NULL) the temp variable and if not NULL, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the result will be a memory leak.

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns an 'int', not a 'char'.  Strongly suggest 1) check for the value to be EOF 2) assign the returned value to a 'int', not a char, then if the value is 'ok' then assign to the `char s*` array

Comment: regarding: ` printf("Your String:- %s \nAnd It's length:- %lu\nAnd the Size:- %lu",s,(strlen(s)),sizeof(s)` the 's' is a pointer, so this sizeof(s) returns the size of a pointer.  Similar considerations exist for the statement: `printf(" \nThe size of b is %lu",(sizeof(b)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that `char *s;` doesn't initialize `s`

So the first time you enter in `realloc`, you pass it an invalid pointer: undefined behaviour.

```
char *s = NULL;
```

is more like it.

Answer (score 0):

`char *b;` -> This means that `b` is a character pointer. It is only capable of addressing a string which has already been declared. Meaning it cannot hold the string as a whole. It should be initialized with the base address of an already existing string or can hold the address of a dynamically allocated string. Therefore,

```
char *b = "how are you"; //is what causing you the problem.
```

Instead, you could try:

```
char b[] = "how are you"; //which should work fine!
```

Cheers!

Comment: Given char *p = "x" and char a[] = "x", sizeof(p)==sizeof(char*) and sizeof(a)==strlen("x").

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that you never initially allocated s, sizeof(b) == sizeof(char*), not the length of the string.

Comment: Thank you so Much !!! This Is what I was looking for. So how can Get the size of string in bytes ??

Comment: @SMITPATIL, use strlen(b).

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is exhibiting several problems:

1. the pointer: `s` is not initialized. Passing an uninitialized pointer to `realloc()` results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.
2. the correct signature for `main()`, when the parameters are not going to be used is:

   int main( void )
3. variables passed to `realloc()` should be `size_t`, not `int`.
4. when calling `realloc()`, assign the result to a temp variable then check that variable for NULL.  If NULL, then cleanup and exit.
5. the function: `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.
6. Never trust the user to do the expected thing, so also check if the returned value from `getchar()` is EOF.
7. the expression: `sizeof( s )` or `sizeof( b )` will return the sizeof a pointer (4 or 8 depending on the underlying architecture and certain compile parameters.
8. There are a number of 'implicit' conversions of data types in the posted code.  Such implicit conversions can cause problems.  Best to eliminate such implicit conversions.
9. the posted code leaks memory.

In the following proposed code:

1. the reason for each header file being included is documented
2. all the known problems with the code are corrected
3. proper checking for errors is implemented
4. each line that was changed or added is commented via `//<<--`

Note: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, suggest:

```
gcc  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 mysource.c -o mysource
```

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // getchar(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // realloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>   // strlen()


int main( void )
{
    char *s = NULL;               //<<-- initialized
    char *b = "how are you";

    printf("Enter the string:- ");
    for( size_t i =0; 1; i++ )     //<<-- need 'size_t' for 'realloc()'
    {
        char *temp = realloc( s, i+1 );  //<<-- proper way to call 'realloc()'
        if( !temp )    // <<-- checking for failure and handling failure
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( s );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        s = temp;

        int k = getchar();      //<<--  returns 'int', not 'char'

        if( k == EOF || k == '\n' )  //<<-- a user can do almost anything
        {
            s[i]= '\0';
            break;
        }

        else                    //<<-- input 'good' so update array
        {                       
            s[i] = (char)k;     
        }                       
    }

    // terminate format strings with '\n' 
    // so data is immediately displayed
    // honor the right edge of a printed page (~column 80)
    // when listing the program
    printf("Your String:- %s \nAnd It's length:- %lu\nAnd the Size:- %lu\n",
           s,
           (strlen(s)),
           sizeof(s));     // <<-- yields the size of a pointer
    printf(" \nThe size of b is %lu\n",
           (sizeof(b)));   // <<-- yields the size of a pointer
}
```